# Prime factorization in a functional language

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, primes, prime-factoring

I'm writing in OCaml, trying to give a (somewhat) efficient implementation of prime factorization.  I figure the best representation of a number 2 or more is in a list of exponents.  For simplicity with consing I'll do it in decreasing order of primes.  So 2 would be [1] and 3 would be [1;0] and 4 would be [2], and 5 [1;0;0].

I was thinking of using the sieve idea to take a number `n` and look for all possible divisors between 2 and `sqrt(n)`.  Then divide by any divisor and recurse.  However, every implementation that I can think of seems to involve repeatedly searching over a list and that seems just unnecessarily inefficient.  The outline of my solution is best stated in this code

```
let rec pf n =
  if (n=2) then ([1], 0)
  else let sq = int_of_float ( (float_of_int n) ** 0.5 ) in
  let primes = getPrimes sq in
  match earliestDiv n primes with
  | None -> n::(zero_list (n-1))
  | Some (x, i) -> let subproblem pf (n/x) in
              increment subproblem i
```

The helper functions here would be:

- `getPrimes` which takes an int and returns a list of all prime numbers less-than-or-equal to it.
- `earliestDiv` which takes an int `n` and list of ints `lst`, returns an int*int option corresponding to the earliest number in `lst` which divides `n`.  That will be the first coordinate of the tuple; the second coordinate will return the index of this prime `x` in the list of primes.
- `increment` will take an int list and index, and increase by 1 the number located at the index.

All of these helper functions keep making lists, and passing through lists, and so on.  And in fact, I often feel like I'm doing this in functional programming.  I often have the sense that I'm unnecessarily iterating over lists whereas in imperative languages I would be writing code that is more efficient.  Perhaps it's just in my head, and when writing in imperative languages I less often notice how many resources are going into some of the list operations I use.  But if I'm missing some important technique that could prevent repeatedly scanning lists, I'd be curious to hear it.

The question: Is it necessary to repeatedly make and iterate over lists in order to write this function?

Comment: @Ken White the question is whether it is necessary to repeatedly make and iterate over lists. That sounds like a programming question to me.

Comment: @KenWhite Question updated.

Comment: As a side comment you might want to try writing code to multiply two numbers in your representation. My claim is that it is will be cumbersome to line up the corresponding primes. If you have the list start with the exponent of 2, alignment is automatic.

Comment: As another side comment, iterating through a list is no slower than iterating across an array. It's when you require random access that there is a difference.

Comment: You might also consider what your representation would look like for a 100-digit prime (say).

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I think I see what you're saying, but for such purposes wouldn't it be enough to just reverse the list at the end?  If I don't write the lists in reverse order, then the segment `n::(zero_list (n-1))` would have to use `(zero_list (n-1)) @ [n]` which I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) is essentially having to iterate through a list.  Since the program will do this repeatedly, that sounds expensive.  But again, I could be way off, that was just the reason for my decision there.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Interesting point--I suppose a list of primes is better?  Then a 100-digit prime would have length-one representation, but then that number +1 would have some very long length.  Hm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you end up indexing a list, or filling a list with default elements up to a fixed size, lists are most probably the wrong data structure. For prime factorisation, you probably want an implementation of a sparse array. Maps would be a better (if not optimal) implementation than fixed-size lists.